# How to show test info in console using androidStudio and gradle?

Tags: testing, console, gradle, android-studio

I just created a project with androidStudio, I added the structure of tests, and can see the test results with the format of xml/html.

My question is how could I see the test output in console?

You can check the project on https://github.com/kolyjjj/process_killer

Answer (score 0):

It seems the output will show in console when you write Local unit tests. Located at module-name/src/test/java/.
But in Instrumented tests,Located at module-name/src/androidTest/java/,output did't show in the console,It will show in logcat.